# Why I can not run my electron application after electron-forge make command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

I have written small Electron application. For building and packaging purposes i have downloaded following node package `npm install -g electron-forge`
When i run following command `electron-forge make` following directory is created with contents in it: [image]

Above directory contains file `your-app.exe`. When i run this file i get following screen: [image]

When i check the appropriate directory, files are presented there:[image]

In development mode, when i try to start application with command `electron-forge start` application runs wthout any problems.

I can not distribute my application and really need your help: What could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: Does your index.html have js inlined? Perhaps using imports or requires? Try double checking to make sure the names are exactly the same. I've had this issue before, turned out I had an import written with the wrong case (had uppercase instead of lowercase and the import/file name weren't an exact match)